# Multi Site PHP-Apache docker

Tags: php, docker, apache, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been trying to build a multi site Apache docker but all in vain.
Here is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
    app:
      container_name: Core
      build:
        context: ./conf/core
        args:
            UID: ${UID:-1000}
      env_file:
        - "./.env"
      ports:
        - "${HTTP_PORT:-80}:80"
        - "${HTTPS_PORT:-443}:443"
      volumes:
        - ./../application:/var/www/html
        - ./conf/core/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
        - ./conf/core/openssl.cnf:/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
        - ./conf/ssl:/etc/apache2/ssl
        - ./logs/apache:/var/log/apache2
      networks:
        - abmmhasan-net

networks:
  abmmhasan-net:
    driver: bridge
```

The docker file

```bash
FROM php:8.2-apache

# Configureing Apache
#ENV APACHE_RUN_USER=#$UID
#ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP=#$UID
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2
RUN rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf
RUN rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
ADD ./sites/*.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
RUN echo "ServerName site1.local" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN echo "ServerName site2.local" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN a2ensite *
RUN a2enmod rewrite ssl socache_shmcb vhost_alias

# Required installations/updates
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y

RUN apt install sudo -y && apt clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /var/cache/apt/archives/*

# Add synced system user
ARG UID
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $UID -d /home/devuser devuser && \
    mkdir -p /home/devuser/.composer && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser /home/devuser
USER devuser

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

And the ./sites/site1.local.conf (same way the site2 with site2 directory) file

```
<VirtualHost site1.local:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@site1.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        ServerName site1.local

        <Directory /var/www/html/site1>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also added following in my hosts file

```
192.168.50.4 site1.local
192.168.50.4 site2.local
```

Tried to have single docker container with multiple site hosted in single place but instead of loading the sites from defined directory it loads from `/var/www/html/` only!!

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP? Check whether requesting static files work to rule this out

Comment: This is tagged with PHP because it is built on php-apache container & the file running in are of php. I dunno if the problem is with PHP-Apache docker or Just the Apache..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several try I was able to resolve it. What I did was,

- Updated  to <VirtualHost *:80>. ServerName directive used instead to separate the sites.
- Deleted the 000-default.conf & default-ssl.conf
- No need to add ServerName in apache2.conf

Updated code now available in https://github.com/abmmhasan/localhost

Answer (score 0):

in your hosts file it wont be `127.0.0.1 site1.local` it would be something else, check your docker containers local ip address, and put that there `docker_ip_here site1.local`

use this command to get its ip address, replace `container_name_or_id` with your docket name/id

```
docker inspect \
  -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

if on windows use this command

```
docker inspect \
  -f "{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" container_name_or_id
```

Comment: after running the command I got the IP 192.168.112.2 which didn't work after hosts entry. My local IP is 192.168.50.64. Also I think You've missed something I said above in last line.

Comment: you also need to enable the `Directory` attribute to the conf files

Comment: Added directory command but didn't workout. Check above, code is updated.